# Punctuation Pattern Analyzer

Tags: python, excel, pandas, nltk

Aim: I am studying the punctuation patterns occurring within sentences usage. The following code (got from online) returns punctuation in sentences !.;. for my_str. I am trying to extract sentences and corresponding punctuation marks within the sentences and send it to excel in the expected output format.

```
# define punctuation
punctuations = '''.?![]()"",:;-/'''

my_str = "Really! This is a sample sentence. The cat sat on the mat; the dog slept."

# To take input from the user
# my_str = input("Enter a string: ")

# remove punctuation from the string
punct = ""
for char in my_str:
   if char in punctuations:
       punct = punct + char

# display the unpunctuated string
print(punct)
```

output expected.

```
Sentences                                    Punct_pattern
Really! This is a sample sentence.            !.
The cat sat on the mat; the dog slept.        ;.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from your example that you split each sentence with a period and all of your sentences are in one string:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_str = "Really! This is a sample sentence. The cat sat on the mat; the dog slept."
delimiter = '.'

raw_sentences = pd.DataFrame()
raw_sentences['sentences'] = pd.Series(my_str.split(delimiter)).replace('', np.nan).dropna()
raw_sentences['sentences']  = raw_sentences['sentences'] + delimiter # add the delimiter back into the data frame

raw_sentences['punctuation_pattern'] = raw_sentences['sentences'].str.replace('[a-zA-z0-9\s\s+]',"") # Remove all characters
raw_sentences.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Output:

```
print(raw_sentences)
                                 sentences punct_pattern
0       Really! This is a sample sentence.            !.
1   The cat sat on the mat; the dog slept.            ;.
```

The code above also doesn't explicitly use the punctuation you defined in your sample, it works by creating a new column by stripping the letters, numbers and white space from the sentence: `str.replace('[a-zA-z0-9\s\s+]',"")`.

Hopefully that helps.